# Universal Linking Uploading the JSON to the HTTPS Server

Tags: ios, json, https, velo

I am trying to implement universal linking in my IOS Application. I have the apple documentation and am following the steps, but I come to a problem with uploading my "apple-app-site-association" file to the root of my HTTPS web server. I am using Wix.com to build my website and using Google Admin for the website domain. I have no idea where to upload this file and I looked all over the Wix documentation and came up with nothing. Is this a problem with Wix? Or am I missing something else?

---

Apple Documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html

Wix: https://www.wix.com

Comment: Same issue here... Did you solve it?

Comment: No I haven't found any solution yet

Comment: Still no solution? I'll try to see if Wix.com supports it.

Comment: I looked for a while, but found nothing, and no support/help topics covering this issue. I guess wix does not support this.

Comment: @Jonny I guess. I still have not found anything